# Problem with getting root privileges

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I got problem with getting root privileges for my account
I added root privileges to my account using below commands

```
sudo visudo
myusername    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
file save
system reboot
```

but I still dont have root privileges e.g. when I try to execute `mkdir /test` I getting error with lack of privileges, I dont know whats going on because myusername is in sudo group

Comment: The privileges granted in the sudoers file only apply when the command is *invoked using sudo* i.e. `sudo mkdir /test`

Comment: is there any option to omit sudo?

Comment: you could do `sudo su` to become a root shell, and thereafter do stuff as root without needing a `sudo` prefix.

Comment: Or `sudo   -i /bin/bash`, but both this and `sudo su` are discouraged among professional system managers. Learning to use `sudo` offers more control, and a greater ability to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Hello. Another good habit to get into is always include the version of Ubuntu you are using with any question.

Comment: Thanks for answers! I will study more deeply user/permissions to get full picture